# Server To Connect Mobile Device Too

Tags: android, sql-server, google-app-engine

Hi all i am new to the server application side of things.

so here is my questions. I have a mobile app that i would like to connect to a server based on location, ID number, and name. When the user enters in the information into a text field and clicks submit, the information will be submitted to the server from the app on the phone, and based on the information the server the server will return the user with a number and there will also be a desktop client that will receive the notification that a new user has been registered or added to the que list.

Could anyone give me a background on things i need to study, and things i will need to do this?
also what would the implementation behind something like this be. Also would it be costly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Android & AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android) perhaps.

Comment: Does Android AppEngine let me have seperate small databases?

Answer (score 1):

How are your users authenticated? Are you using an SQL database? If you are you will need to make a connection to the database and then authenticate to it with the provided user credentials

Comment: hmm..See thats where i need insite on. How would i go about authenticating the user? The thing is i will have a server and on the server i will need several databases that the user can connect to based on location and name. So from my app the user will enter there location or select there location from the list, and then enter the name, and click submit, then i would like the info to be sent to the server and based on location add the user to the correct database, and return them a ID number and notify the desktop app that is connected to the certain database. Hope this makes sense.